# How to check if text widget has certain content?

Tags: php, widget, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to check if **Text Widget** has certain content?

To be more specific, I need to check if **Text Widget** content has a specific shortcode that starts with:

> **[button** ...

Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

WordPress shortcodes do not work within text widgets. Why I have no idea but if you need this functionality, it is quite easy to accomplish, simply write this code below in your functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'shortcode_unautop');

add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

your shortcodes should now work in your text widgets!

Comment: Hi Ramzi, thank you for your comment. Yes I'm familiar with that. I already have that in my functions and my shortcode does work in Text Widget. What I need is to check if Text Widget content has that certain shortcode.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter text widgets as well and use the `has_shortcode` function in order find find out if your shortcode was used.

```
function my_filter_widget_text( $widget_text, $instance, $widget ) {
    $tag = 'button';

    if ( has_shortcode( $instance['text'], $tag ) ) {
        $widget_text .= '<p>blub</p>';
    }

    return $widget_text;
}
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'my_filter_widget_text', 1, 3 );
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First you can use a function like this to export a widget content:

```
if(!function_exists('get_dynamic_sidebar'){
function get_dynamic_sidebar($index = 1)
{
    $sidebar_contents = "";
    ob_start();
    dynamic_sidebar($index);
    $sidebar_contents = ob_get_clean();
    return $sidebar_contents;
}
}
```

Than i think this tutorial ken help you to finish your work:

[Tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-improving-shortcodes-with-the-has_shortcode-function/)

Comment: I'm using the exact same function from that Tutorial. I was just wondering if there is an easy way to check if text widget has_shortcode('button') then do something..

Answer (score 0):

wordpress's `has_shortcode()` will search a string for the existence of a specific shortcode. Codex documentation can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_shortcode).

Comment: Hi, I'm familiar with has_shortcode and how to check it in $post->post_content. I just don't have enough knowledge to implement it this on Text Widget content. Thank you.